# Python/Selenium - Can't get HREF value of a tag

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I have this HTML element:

```
<h2 class="post-title">

    <a href="http://google.com" rel="bookmark">This a link to Google!</a>

</h2>
```

I am using `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('post-title')` to find this piece of HTML.

**But how can I extract only the value of the "href" tag?**

I've tried:

> driver.get_attribute('href')

returns 'none'

Thanks

Comment: Indeed the sibling whose tag is `h2` has no href attribute and this is the one you target via searching elements `by_class_name('post-title')` . It is the sibling `<a></a>` which does.

Comment: Problem is, if I try to find all the <a> in the web page, I end up with 90+ links where there are only 10 that interest me. How can I extract the data from THIS piece of HTML?

Comment: If Andersson's answer does what you need, select his answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

- you're trying to find `h2` elements instead of `a`
- you're trying to get attribute value from `WebDriver` instance

Try below code to get required output:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h2.post-title>a').get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the sibling whose tag is `h2` has no href attribute and this is the one you target via searching elements `by_class_name('post-title')` . It is the sibling `<a></a>` which does.

What about searching by xpath ? If `'post-title'` is a unique class identifier, you can search for your element as follows

```
xpth = "//*[@class='post-title']/a"
a_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpth)
```

and finally

```
href = a_element.get_attribute('href')
```

---

Something you could do from what you (almost) have

```
h2_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('post-title')
a_element = h2_element.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
href = a_element.get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 1):

`href` belongs to `<a>`  tag; so first you have to reach till that element as following:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h2[@class="post-title"]/a')

attribute_value = elem.get_attribute('href')
```